# Does PNG support non-transparent pictures?

Tags: transparency, png, background

I'm doing an assignment for school and I can't find the answer to my question  anywhere! I'm making a logo for a game that I have designed, it's the most frustrating thing ever! If you know, please tell me asap.

Comment: You'll find most formats that support transparency also implicitly support non transparency.

Comment: I don't know how it couldn't. If a format only allowed transparency then they would always be see through...

Comment: @ZachSaucier: not really. One can even imagine a 1-bit transparent file format, where 0 is transparent and 1 is not. *Supporting* transparency does not mean every - or even a single one! - pixel must be transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can "flatten" your image using a program like gimp.

**Aditional info.**

Every raster format support non transparent images, but only few does support transparency.

The transparency on a png file is an aditional channel, this is, you have your rgb image (a simple graph or photo) and besides that you have one more channel that you can use or not. In that channel you can have some parts in black and some in white or inclusive you can have a complete grayscale photo.

---

Some other raster formats like gif only support one very specific color in its pallete as transparent For example an exact green. If you have a simmilar green next to it it wont be transparent.

Comment: I have made PNG files using php that had alpha-style transparency defined but no alpha channel. The image looked normal in editing software without any visual indication it had alpha. I think a quick way to eliminate the transparency is to "save-as" a TIFF, close then reopen and then export as a PNG.

Comment: Yes, that way you simply "drop" the information on the transparency. But I would recomend another format, like BMP becouse some subsets of TIFF does support transparencies.